# rails belongs_to multiple models how to create in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models : idea, knowledges and comments.
Idea and knowledge both has_many comments.
Comment belongs_to idea and knowledge.

But idk how to write create for comment.
this is idea part i wrote before, now i want to add knowledge part.

```
def create
@idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
@comment = @idea.comments.create(comment_params)
redirect_to idea_path(@idea)
```

Comment: comment for idea and knowledge present on same view or different ?

Comment: Are you trying to associate an idea with a knowledge?

Comment: @hashrocket no they just both have comments

Comment: @Nickey they have different views

Comment: you can make two separate routes, handling the different kinds of comments. Or put a conditional, e.g. `if params[:idea_id] ... elsif params[:knowledge_id] ...`

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a bad design, even if you fix it somehow now, it will backfire in future. You need to use `Polymorphic Association`. It is standard and recommended solution in your use-case.

You can read about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). There are lots of tutorials available online, just google it. There's a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) too which solves your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement "**Polymorphic Association**" here. You can refer it from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

For your requirement, you can do model design as follow,

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Idea < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Knowledge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```